# Ubuntu stuck on apt-get update

Tags: networking, apt

Running Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial 64-bit minimal

when running apt-get update it hangs forever at 0% for de.archive.ubuntu.com

I tried pining google.com and I get 100% packets lost

I even uncommented "precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100"

I'm stuck guys. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could be a connection issue, try reconnecting to internet service.

Comment: check your network connection.

Answer (score -1):

it seems there is a permission issue, so use sudo as prefix in terminal like:

`sudo apt-get update`

`[sudo] password for username: enter your password here`

as well as also check your internet connection there, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

open your terminal (with ctrl+alt+t or typing terminal in your dash) and write `sudo vim /etc/resolve.conf` (i use vim you can use your editor but it is better that your editor hasn't gui like gedit) and then type your password and replace the ip address next of the nameserver with 8.8.8.8 and then type

you can test this with 4.2.2.4 or other dns address